# How to start application without going back to LXDE?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running chromium browser at start up on raspberry, my question is after closing my chromium browser am trying to run another application without going back to desktop(LXDE).. am new user.. please help me out

Comment: What do you mean not going back to LXDE? What is the other application?

Answer (score 0):

I presume when you close chromium you go back to the shell.
Did you try to type the name of the program you want to launch?
Like the same way you launched chromium.

Try to type `nano text_file` or `omxplayer video/audio_file`